# Base JavaScript object on another object using class and constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-6

ES6 introduces `class`, `extends`, `constructor` etc. making prototype-based inheritance quite easy. I want to base an object, constructed via a class' constructor on another object. What is the cleanest way to do that in this new syntactic way of constructing objects?

```
class A {
  constructor(json) {
     let base = JSON.parse(json);
     this.prototype = base; // ????
  }
}
```

I would use `extends`, but since the object is passed down there is no other class definition here

Comment: What would you like the end structure to be? Where will the JSON properties exists, and what prototype chain should be constructed? (Or in other words, how are you intending to use this...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `json` is unique per instance you should change `this` rather than `this.prototype`. You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for that:

```
class A {
  constructor(json) {
     let base = JSON.parse(json);
     Object.assign(this, base);
  }
}
```

`Object.assign` copies (by reference) the *enumerable* and *own* properties from arguments 1-n onto argument 0. It's a native implementation of [`_.assign`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) (aka `_.extend`).

If, instead, you want to use a single `json` for *all* instances, you don't need to pass it to the constructor. See @Quentin Roy's answer.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, but I was told `Object.assign(this, ..)` is **a bad idea**. Not sure why, except unexpected side-effects which are not in your control.

Comment: The side effect is exactly what you are trying to achieve here - to mutate the object in the first argument.

Comment: `Object.assign(this, ...)` is __not__ an inherently bad thing. Like any other language feature or pattern it's important to understand how to use it. If you want to _extend_ an object rather than augmenting it, the standard pattern is `const extended = Object.assign({}, baseObject, extraObject)`, but that isn't what you want here (since it wouldn't actually update your class instance).

Comment: The only side effect that may happens is that the properties of `base` will have the priority over the method defined in `A` as they will be directly part of the instances while the later will be in their `prototype`. If it is the kind of behaviour you want, then go on. If you want to avoid that, you may need to check before inserting any property of `base` if it is not already part of `A.prototype`. It can be easily performed with something like `Object.keys(base).filter((k) => !k in A.prototype).forEach`. But that starts to be a bite hacky.

Answer (score 1):

If your json object is an argument of your constructor, it cannot be part of the prototype chain. As @joews pointed out, in that case the only thing you can do is to copy its properties in the constructor of your class.

If you want your json object to be part of the prototype chain, I would do something like this:

```
var base = JSON.parse(json)

// Creates a Base class based on the base object.
class Base {} // or function Base(){} which is exactly the same.
Base.prototype = base;

// Extends it.
class A extends Base {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

As an alternative you *could* do:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
  }
}
Object.assign(A.prototype, JSON.parse(json));
```

But I found the previous solution cleaner because `base` is a distinct prototype in the prototype chain instead of being merged with `A`'s prototype. This has several advantages:

1. In the latter solution, a property of `base` will overwrite a property of `A` if they have the same name. In the first solution, both properties will still exists (though `A`'s one will have the priority, you can still access the parent's one with `super`).
2. With the first solution, you can do `aInstance instanceof Base`. You can't with the later.
3. Conceptually, I find the first solution much more elegant.

Comment: You _could_ `Object.assign(this.prototype, base)`, but that would lead to _extremely_ strange behaviour - all instances would effectively change each time a new instance is created. That would be a __bad idea__.

Comment: Yes, very bad idea. What you could do though is to do it *outside* A's constructor.

Comment: Well actually, it looks like it doesn't work (with babel at least). `this.prototype` is still `undefined` in the `constructor` (which I personally found perfectly OK and safer).

Comment: Yep, this is the answer if the aim is to affect all instances. I thought JSON was probably unique per instance because it's a constructor arg.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't know that.